# getting form results from another website

Tags: php, html, forms, parsing

So this is what I am trying to achieve :

First website (I don't own it):

A form that contain an input type text and a button when you click the button and according to your text you receive a response (label) : true or false

Second website (Mine) :

Contain a form (input type text + button) and I want when the user click the button he recieve the same response from the first website .

What I did :

Using simplehtmldom_1_5 I was able to parse the first website html

What I am missing :

Injecting the text value and getting the results

Comment: Ask for permission of the first site. Perhaps they have an API you can use?

Comment: what input method of the first website, if it's GET method the URL should be changed, you can get Value from here. But if it POST method it will be more difficult.

Comment: how do you get the data? does the other site's form action call the form on your site? if so, you could just pass the data via arguments and have your form process the results.